# Property of the remainder term in the Euler-Maclaurin formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n\log i$.

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals, euler-maclaurin, bernoulli-polynomials

From [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation.), I'm having trouble understanding $$R_{m,n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{m,n}+O(n^{-m}).$$ I worked out $$R_{m,n}=\int_1^{n}\frac{P_m(x)}{mx^m}~ dx$$
where $P_m(x)$ is a periodic Bernoulli polynomial, so
$$\begin{align}
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{m,n}-R_{m,n}\right|&=\left|\int_n^{\infty}\frac{P_m(x)}{mx^m}~ dx\right|\\
&\le\int_n^{\infty}\frac{|P_m(x)|}{mx^m}~ dx\\
&\le Mn^{1-m}
\end{align}$$
so I get $O(n^{1-m})$ which isn't desired.