# Verifying Big O of remainder term when deriving Stirling's approximation formula

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals, euler-maclaurin, bernoulli-polynomials

I am trying to verify the following statement mentioned in an wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation), the statement is used to derive the stirling's approximation .  I also took some help from another post ([Property of the remainder term in the Euler-Maclaurin formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n\log i$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184734/property-of-the-remainder-term-in-the-euler-maclaurin-formula-for-sum-i-1n)).
$$R_{m,n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{m,n}+O(n^{-m})$$
 Here's what i tried.
$$R_{m,n}=\int_1^{n}\frac{P_m(x)}{mx^m}~ dx \text{
, where $P_m(x)$ is a periodic Bernoulli polynomial.}$$
\begin{align}
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty} R_{m,n}-R_{m,n}\right|&=\left|\int_n^{\infty}\frac{P_m(x)}{mx^m}~ dx\right|\\
&\le\int_n^{\infty}\frac{|P_m(x)|}{mx^m}~ dx\\
\end{align}
 Since R.H.S is an improper integral we have

\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_n^{t}\frac{|P_m(x)|}{mx^m}~ dx\\
\end{align}
Integrating by parts and using the property of periodic bernoulli function $P'_m({x}) = mP_{m-1}(x) $ for $m \ge 3$ we get

\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_n^{t}\frac{|P_m(x)|}{mx^m}~ dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\left|-\frac{P_m(x)}{m(m-1)x^{m-1}} - \frac{P_{m-1}(x)}{(m-1)(m-2)x^{m-2}} - \frac{P_{m-2}(x)}{(m-2)(m-3)x^{m-3}}  ... -\frac{P_{2}(x)}{x}\right|^t_n\right)\\
\end{align}

Then evaluating integral from $t $ to $n$ we get
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}F(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\left(-\frac{P_m(t)}{m(m-1)t^{m-1}} - \frac{P_{m-1}(t)}{(m-1)(m-2)t^{m-2}} - \frac{P_{m-2}(t)}{(m-2)(m-3)t^{m-3}} ... -\frac{P_{2}(t)}{t}\right)- \left(-\frac{P_m(n)}{m(m-1)n^{m-1}} - \frac{P_{m-1}(n)}{(m-1)(m-2)n^{m-2}} - \frac{P_{m-2}(n)}{(m-2)(m-3)n^{m-3}} ... -\frac{P_{2}(n)}{n}\right)\right)\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}F(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\left(-\frac{B_m}{m(m-1)t^{m-1}} - \frac{B_{m-1}}{(m-1)(m-2)t^{m-2}} - \frac{B_{m-2}}{(m-2)(m-3)t^{m-3}} ... -\frac{B_{2}}{t}\right)- \left(-\frac{B_m}{m(m-1)n^{m-1}} - \frac{B_{m-1}}{(m-1)(m-2)n^{m-2}} - \frac{B_{m-2}}{(m-2)(m-3)n^{m-3}} ... -\frac{B_{2}}{n}\right)\right)\\
\end{align}

Finally taking the limit
\begin{align}
=\left(\left(0+ 0 + 0 ....+0\right)+ \frac{B_m}{m(m-1)n^{m-1}} + \frac{B_{m-1}}{(m-1)(m-2)n^{m-2}} + \frac{B_{m-2}}{(m-2)(m-3)n^{m-3}} ... +\frac{B_{2}}{n}\right)\\
\end{align}
Therefore i get $O({n^{1-m}})$ , but in wikipedia it  is given that it is bounded by $O({n^{-m}})$. I think i am doing something wrong here, any help is greatly appreciated -:)

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
R_{m,n}  = \frac{{( - 1)^{m + 1} B_{m + 1} }}{{m(m + 1)}}\left( {\frac{1}{{n^m }} - 1} \right) + R_{m + 1,n}  \\ = \frac{{( - 1)^{m + 1} B_{m + 1} }}{{m(m + 1)}}\left( {\frac{1}{{n^m }} - 1} \right) + \int_1^n {\frac{{P_{m + 1} (x)}}{{(m + 1)x^{m + 1} }}dx} ,
$$
whence
$$
R_{m, \infty }  - R_{m,n}  = \frac{{( - 1)^m B_{m + 1} }}{{m(m + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^m }} + \int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{P_{m + 1} (x)}}{{(m + 1)x^{m + 1} }}dx} \\ = \frac{{( - 1)^m B_{m + 1} }}{{m(m + 1)}}\frac{1}{{n^m }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^m }}} \right) = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^m }}} \right).
$$

Comment: Thanks @Gary. Almost understood except how did you arrive at $ \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^m }}} \right)$ for the $\int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{P_{m + 1} (x)}}{{(m + 1)x^{m + 1} }}dx}$ remainder term . The expansion of the remainer integral $\int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{P_{m + 1} (x)}}{{(m + 1)x^{m + 1} }}dx}$ is 
$$ =  -{\frac{1}{(m +1)}}\frac{B_{m + 2}}{(m+2)}\frac{1}{n^{m+1}} -{\frac{B_{m + 3}}{(m +2)(m + 3)}}\frac{1}{n^{m+2}} + \int_n^{ + \infty }{ \frac{P_{m + 3} (x)}{m+3} \frac{1}{x^{m+3}}dx})$$
From which we can see it is $ \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{m + 1} }}} \right)$

Comment: The $P_{m+1}(x)$ can be bounded by a constant depending only on $m$ and the rest follows by integrating $1/x^{m+1}$. What you do is correct, but we aimed for $1/n^m$ and the crude estimate on the integral was enough to achieve it.

Comment: Understood now. Thanks @Gary.